# How to use generic list that takes in derived classes that implements a common interface

Tags: .net, generics

Lets say I have a generic interface (VB.NET):

```
Public Interface IBase(Of T As {IBase(Of T)})
    Property Parent() As T
```

And I have 2 classes that implements the interface

```
Public Class Derive1
    Implements IBase(Of Derive1)
    Public Property Parent() As Derive1 Implements IBase(Of Derive1).Parent

Public Class Derive2
    Implements IBase(Of Derive2)
    Public Property Parent() As Derive2 Implements IBase(Of Derive2).Parent
```

How do I use the generic List that can accept both Derive1 and Derive2 such that:

```
genList.Add(Derive1)
genList.Add(Derive2)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between IBase and IBasicPortfolio?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code sample. IBase is the common interface that both derive classes implements. I have updated the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Make Derive1 and Derive2 implement a common interface, then create a List of that interface.  For example, suppose you want to iterate over your generic list and have a method such as CountChildren that you can perform on both the Derive1 and Derive2 objects in that list.  First, you'll want to create an interface, like this:

```
Public Interface ICalculations
    Function CountChildren() As Integer
End Interface
```

Then, you'll want to set up Derive1 and Derive2 so that they implement this interface.  Here is what that could look like:

```
Public Class Derive1
    Implements IBasicPortfolio(Of Derive1)
    Implements ICalculations
    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set
            m_Value = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Value As Integer
    Public Property [Next]() As Derive1
        Get
            Return m_Next
        End Get
        Set
            m_Next = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Next As Derive1
    Public Function CountChildren() As Integer
        Return 1 + [Next].CountChildren()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Derive2
    Implements IBasicPortfolio(Of Derive2)
    Implements ICalculations
    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set
            m_Value = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Value As Integer
    Public Property [Next]() As Derive1
        Get
            Return m_Next
        End Get
        Set
            m_Next = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Next As Derive1
    Public Function CountChildren() As Integer
        Return 1 + [Next].CountChildren()
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you can create a List of ICalculations, which can contain both Derive1 and Derive2 objects:

```
Dim foo = New List(Of ICalculations)()

foo.Add(New Derive1())
foo.Add(New Derive2())

For Each bar As var In foo
    bar.CountChildren()
Next
```